# How to retrieve class attributes in test when a method is patched with custom method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a python test as below and it does below things:

1. Patch `baz` method of `FooClass` with custom method.
2. Invoke `BarClass` from test.
3. `BarClass` creates instance of `FooClass` and sets class attribute `db_url` of `FooClass` to some value and runs the method `baz`.

How can I retrieve `FooClass.db_url` in test to do some asserts?

Here is the simplified code:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch

from bar import BarClass
from foo import FooClass

def baz_dummy_method(cls):
    """ Mock version of Foo.baz"""

    engine = create_engine(cls.db_url)
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(
            """INSERT INTO "Employee"(Id, Name) VALUES ('1000', 'John Doe');"""
        )

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(FooClass, "baz", new=baz_dummy_method)
    def test_run(self,):
        """ This test case is to verify the simple happy path scenario"""

        # This BarClass invokes FooClass and sets its property db_url.
        BarClass()
        
        # Here I want to assert that FooClass is called once 
        # and would like to retrieve db_url of FooClass, how can I do that?
```

**bar_class.py**:

```
from foo_class import FooClass

class BarClass():
    def __init__(self): 
        foo = FooClass()
        foo.db_url = 'blah'
        foo.baz()
```

**foo_class.py**:

```
class FooClass():
    db_url = ''

    def __init__(self): 
        print('entered foo class init')

    def baz(self):
        # Does some db related activities here using db_url
        print(self.db_url)
```

Comment: When you say that `BarClass` "invokes `FooClass`", do you mean creates an instance and calls methods or sets attributes on that instance? Or is `db_url` a class variable? Does the use of `FooClass` by `BarClass` somehow involve the patched `baz` method? Might you instead need to patch the whole class?

Comment: @Blckknght added more details and I believe gives more clarity to my question. Please let me know if my question is still not clear.

Comment: `BarClass.__init__` creates a `FooClass` object, then sets the `db_url` member of that object, then throws it away.  It does not change the class default value.  `FooClass.db_url` will still be `''`.

Comment: @TimRoberts But when `FooClass.baz` method is running, it is printing the value that is set by `BarClass`. In my above example, it is printing value "blah". Is it possible to get  this value in test class to do some assertion?

Comment: In `BarClass.__init__`, you're printing the value of `foo.db_url`, which you just changed.  `FooClass.db_url` is still an empty string.  You can print that to see,  If you want to change the class value, then write `FooClass.db_url = 'blah'`, not `foo.db_url = "blah"`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your time. I was thinking how to get instance variable in test but it actually is a class variable and I was able to get simply as `FooClass.db_url`. Thank you so much.